# How do you install an HP Envy 4250 printer with the Ubuntu operating system?

Tags: software-installation

How do you install the HP Envy 4520 printer using the Ubuntu operating system?
When we tried to install the printer it said it did not recognize our operating system which in Ubuntu.

Comment: You should be able to download the driver from here: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/other/envy_4520_series.html

Comment: Wait a moment: where did you see that _'it did not recognize your operation system whiwh is Ubuntu'_?  On the printer??? On the PC (which is Ubuntu, I suppose)?  Could you clarify?